# How do i put the id in the middle of the url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have defined a URL like this
URLT = URL/id/URL

How do i put the real value of the id in the 'id' part (/id/)?

```
function(param: Param) {
    return new Promise<boolean>( (resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post<boolean>(URLT+id, options).subscribe( (res => {
        resolve(res);
      }));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript you can create that string in different ways, for example:

```
const myUrl = "http://www.api.com/" + id + "/foo"
```

or better one:

```
const myUrl = `http://www.api.com/${id}/foo`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

cheers

Comment: Thanks. But how to replace it in the post method?

Comment: @habib with `String.replace` ?